# Does Spring Data Elasticsearch supports config and monitor operations?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Does [Spring Data Elasticsearch](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/tree/2.0.1.RELEASE) supports [index management](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-management.html) and [index monitor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/cluster-admin.html) operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use and configure the [`TransportClient`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.namespace) in order to execute all admin and index operations you need to.

Using that client you can then perform any [index management](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-admin-indices.html) and [cluster operations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-admin-cluster.html) supported by the [Java API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index.html).

Comment: Ok, that's useful, but I not fully understand how to use it. I mean, Would I have to use the transport client directly on my code or will Spring Data Rest implement some interface as it usually does so I could consume it to perform those operations?

Comment: You can use the client directly to perform any operation you wish on your ES cluster.

Comment: Do you need any more info regarding this?